# Property of a mapping on the tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be rings and consider the tensor product $A \otimes_R B$. Hartshorne writes that:

To give a homomorphism $A \otimes_R B$ into a ring is the same as to give a homomorphism of $A$ and $B$ into that ring, inducing the same homomorphism on $R$.

I am looking through D&F and I can't find anything verifying this property and I am not sure how to begin proving it on my own.

Why is this true?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras) for a start. Certainly this is in chapter 2 of Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: Free source: see pg 40 of these notes by Milne. http://jmilne.org/math/xnotes/CA.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look.